# how to flatten an array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How to flatten an array in mongodb?

```
Name:[["abc","xvz"]]
```

into this way

```
Name:["abc","xyz"]
```

without using aggregate.

Aggregate will display the result but it shouldn't write the result back to the document.

Comment: You want to output _or_ update the document? _And_ not use the Aggregation...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) as this is a trivial step using `[$unwind][2]`. Here is a simple example. If you want to overwrite you could just use update with the results or send the output of `aggregate` to a new collection with `[$out][2]`.

Below is an example using the MongoDB Shell.

```
>
> use test
switched to db test
> db.test.insertOne({name:[['xyz','abc']]})
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedId" : ObjectId("5dbc28bbefffaafb7d97d7f1")
}
> db.test.aggregate([{"$unwind" : "$name"}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dbc28bbefffaafb7d97d7f1"), "name" : [ "xyz", "abc" ] }
>
```